# How to Upload PySpice in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, anaconda

I am running Jupyter Lab through Anaconda Navigator and am trying to up load the PySpice Module. However, I receive an error message saying 'No module named 'PySpice'. Has anyone else found this and if so, is there another module with the same functionality or another way to import PySpice?
Thank you!

This was my code:

```
import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging
logger = Logging.setup_logging()

from PySpice.Doc.ExampleTools import find_libraries
from PySpice.Probe.Plot import plot
from PySpice.Spice.Library import SpiceLibrary
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Unit import *
```

Comment: Run in a new cell where you want to use that import, `%conda install conda-forge::pyspice` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyspice)) and let it run to completion. It may take a while. When it is complete, restart the kernel and try to run the code with your import statement. Make sure you are using the magic symbol `%` at the start. That is important to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing your active notebook is running.

Comment: <continued> See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install command (you'll want to stick with the conda flavor as much as you can since **Anaconda/conda is your chosen primary package manager**) added in 2019 to enable running install commands in the running notebook and insure the installation occurs in the proper environment that is the same one where the active kernel is running. Minor note: your title should be 'How to **Install** PySpice in Jupyter Lab'.